# Is there a way to convert react component function to string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

There is a component function:

```
function Component() {
    const content = 123 + 456
    return <div>{content}</div>
}
```

**I want to convert the whole function as it is to a string**:

```
function App() {
    const str = Component.toString()
    console.log(str)
    return (
        <div>{str}</div>
    )
}
```

But the result is not what I expected:

```
function Component() {
    const content = 123 + 456;
    return /*#__PURE__*/(0, _jsxRuntime.jsx)("div", {
        children: content
    })
}
```

Here is a sample on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/get-func-str-suo6po)

Comment: You're getting a compiled/transpiled result at runtime, not the original pre-compiled/transpiled code.  Take a step back... What exactly are you trying to achieve and why?

Comment: There is no way you can reproduce the React function component's source code at runtime because their design time representation is transformed/built by React to turn into actual valid Javascript code. JSX is not valid Javascript